# Generic implementation of backend crud actions - react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a MERN project, using MongoDB, and I wish to turn it into a generic form, so for example it could also retrieve data from Monday's API for example.

I am a bit confused as for how would it be the correct, efficient way of doing so.

Right now, my backend consists mainly of the following folders and files:

**server.ts**: responsible for connecting my mongoose to MongoDB:

```
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";

const issueRoutes = require("./routes/issueRoutes");
const usersRoutes = require("./routes/usersRoutes");

dotenv.config();

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

const app: Express = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

const uri: string = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PW}@cluster0.n2k7xvu.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB}`;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(issueRoutes);
app.use(usersRoutes);

mongoose.connect(uri).then(() =>
  app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(
      `[server]: Server is running at https://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`
    );
  })
);
```

Three folders: Models/Routes/Controllers, which are implemented in a standard way, intended to use MongoDB

Example of my issueController, responsible of handling in the backend the api requests:

```
//@ts-nocheck
import { Response, Request } from "express";
import IssueInterface from "../types/IssueInterface";
import Issue from "../models/issueModel";
import { ref, uploadBytes, listAll } from "firebase/storage";

var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

export const getIssueById = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
  try {
    console.log("i'm in issue by id backend");
    const { id } = req.params;
    const body = req.body;
    const issue: IssueInterface | null = await Issue.findOne({ _id: id });
    res.status(200).json(issue);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: "error getIssueById" });
  }
};

export const getAllIssues = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
  try {
    const issues: IssueInterface[] = await Issue.find({});
    res.status(200).json({ issues, msg: "getAllIssues" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ msg: "failed getting issues' images", error: err });
  }
};
//insert issue. retrieve the object id returned by mongodb. add image to firebase storage with id of the issue.
export const createIssue = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
  try {
    const answerDb = await Issue.collection.insertOne(req.body);
    res.json(answerDb.insertedId);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "error createIssue" });
  }
};

export const updateIssueById = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const body = req.body;
    console.log("in update issue by id: ", id);
    const updateIssue: IssueInterface | null = await Issue.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      body
    );

    const allIssue: IssueInterface[] = await Issue.find();
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "User updated!",
      issue: updateIssue,
      issues: allIssue,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "error updateIssueById" });
  }
};

// getAllIssuesSortedByCompanyName
// getAllIssuesSortedByIssueDate
// getAllIssuesSortedBySeverity

export const getAllIssuesSortedBySeverity = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
  try {
    const allIssue: IssueInterface[] = await Issue.find().sort("severity");
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Issues retrieved sorted by severity!",
      issues: allIssue,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "error getAllIssuesSortedBySeverity" });
  }
};

export const getAllIssuesSortedByCompanyName = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
  try {
    const allIssue: IssueInterface[] = await Issue.find().sort("company_name");
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Issues retrieved sorted by company_name!",
      issues: allIssue,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "error getAllIssuesSortedByCompanyName" });
  }
};

export const getAllIssuesSortedByIssueDate = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
  try {
    const allIssue: IssueInterface[] = await Issue.find().sort(
      "start_issue_date"
    );
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Issues retrieved sorted by start_issue_date!",
      issues: allIssue,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "error getAllIssuesSortedByIssueDate" });
  }
};

export const addNewIssueMessage = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
  try {
    const issue = await Issue.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.body._id,
      {
        issue_messages: req.body.issue_messages,
      },
      { $currentDate: { lastModified: true } }
    );
    res
      .status(200)
      .json({ status: 200, data: issue, timeStamp: ObjectID.timeStamp });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error creating new issue: ", err);
  }
};
```

Considering the fact that Controllers is made out of 'many' small functions, how would you make it generic?

I'm missing a piece in the puzzle.

Regards :_)

Comment: If you could pare this down to a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE then it would be easier to engage with.

Comment: Which one are you trying to make as generic? [Note: you don't have to set `Promise<void>` explicitly as a return type of your functions, all `async` functions return "Promise" by default. You should let TS infer the types automatically.]

Comment: Thanks to the both of you for your comments ^^ jcalz, I don't have a specific issue with the code I'm seeking to fix, rather conceptual mentorship. msrumon, I am trying to make the controllers and the server.ts generic. Thanks for the tip regarding the return type, I have updated the code :)

Comment: Let me rephrase: it would help others understand your situation if they could play around with the code themselves.  We don't have access to the all the files you are importing in this code snippet, and even if we did it probably would be bigger than a [mre]. Since we are not sitting at your computer with you, it is in everyone's best interest for the code example to be self-contained.